# Catch "HTTP500 Error"

Tags: python-3.x, facebook-graph-api

I'm querying Facebook with the following code, iterating over a list of page names to get the pages' numeric ID and store it in a dictionary. I keep catching a `HTTP 500 error`, however; this doesn't appear in the short list I present here, though. See code:

```
import json
def FB_IDs(page_name, access_token=access_token):
    """ get page's numeric information """  
    # construct URL 
    base = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4"
    node = "/" + str(page_name)
    parameters = "/?access_token=%s" % access_token
    url = base + node + parameters
    # retrieve data    
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as url:
        data = json.loads(url.read().decode()) 
    return data

pages_ids_dict = {}
for page in pages:
    pages_ids_dict[page] = FacebookIDs(page, access_token)['id']
```

How can I automate this and avoid the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a pretty standard helper function for this, which you might want to look at:

```
### HELPER FUNCTION ###
def request_until_succeed(url):
    """ helper function to catch HTTP error 500"""
    req = urllib.request.Request(url)
    success = False

    while success is False:
        try: 
            response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
            if response.getcode() == 200:
                success = True
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            time.sleep(5)
            print("Error for URL") # use following code if URL shall be printed %s: %s" % (url, datetime.datetime.now()))
    return response.read()
```

Implement that function into yours so your function calls that the URL through that one and you should be fine.